# Excel VBA update fill of cells based off of criteria

Tags: vba, excel, highlight, fill

My code is in VBA and updates the value of a cell based off of two criteria.  I've commented my code fairly extensively, so I'll paste it below first.  I've changed comments by adding two more apostrophes to make is a bit easier to tell the difference between comments and code on this platform.

```
Sub HighlightValues()

'''Shortcut key: ctrl + w

'''Highlights values of corresponding left-most cell, if two conditions are met:
'''The part is in "L" class and all of the rightmost cells are empty

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long, c As Long, d As Long, j As Long, count As Long, k As Long, report As Long
Set ws = Sheets("QAP")

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'''Searches column titles for "Analysis Task Count"
'''where it will start searching for filled boxes on each row
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If InStr(ws.Cells(1, i), "Analysis Task Count") Then
        '''c is the number of column that Analysis Task Count is in
        c = i - 1
    End If
Next

'''Searches column titles for "Required by RPC"
'''where it will search for whether the part is "L' or not
For d = 1 To lastcolumn
    If InStr(ws.Cells(1, d), "Required by RPC") Then
        '''k is the number of column that Required by RPC is in
        k = d
    End If
Next d

'''For each row that part data is in
For i = 11 To lastrow
    count = 0

    '''If any cells past Analysis Task Count are filled, remember that
    For j = c To lastcolumn
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, j)) Then
            count = 1
        End If
    Next j

    '''If the stage is L and all the cells are empty for that row
    If Cells(i, k).Value = ("L") And count = 0 Then
        '''Highlight the first box in green
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(102, 255, 102)
    Else
        '''Or if thats not true, then make that box clear
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone
        report = report + 1
    End If
Next i
MsgBox (report)
End Sub
```

To walk you through the code, (barring the spacing, some formatting didn't carry over), the code first searches for the column number of two critical columns, then in the last for loop, for each row, it searches for whether two criteria are met.  If the criteria are met, a cell turns green, if not, it's filled in blank.  I've spent about an hour confirming that the values returned by k and c are both the correct column number: I don't think that is the issue.  Also, when  I set up a count to see how many times the code goes through the last for loop, and each if statement, I get the correct number of cycles.

This is very frustrating, the only weird thing is that the code executes nearly instantly, so there's no delay at all.  And of course, the cell fill doesn't change.  To test this, I ran the code filling in the cells with an orange color, and there was not change to any cells.

Thank you for any help I can get!

Comment: I don't know what passing in is?  I use Dim to initialize them both, then I figure out the values of them, then I use the values in the last loop

Comment: Why are you setting c to the current column - 1     c = i - 1   . It is then looking through columns starting at c.  Without knowing your data, my test has nothing in c so it always gets a count = 1 and never goes into the if statement to color the cell

Comment: FYI, you can get the last row and column like this   .    For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.count     or     For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.count

Answer (score 0):

The part responsible for searching for Analysis Task Count worksheet doesn't look correct to me.

```
For i = 1 To lastrow         '<---- why [lastrow]? should be [lastcolumn]
    If InStr(ws.Cells(1, i), "Analysis Task Count") Then
        '''c is the number of column that Analysis Task Count is in
        c = i - 1            '<---- why subtracting 1?
    End If
Next
```

If you are searching through the column titles why do you use [lastrow] counter as upper bound for your loop. Also, I don't understand why do you subtract 1 after you find the column with such header.

Because of that you have incorrect column index and you compare incorrect sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

1st.
    Change:  ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1)
    To:      ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1)
This has no effect, but "more right".

2. Hmmm

   ```
   For i = 1 To lastrow
       If InStr(ws.Cells(1, i), "Analysis Task Count") Then
           c = i - 1
   ```

Change lastrow to be lastcolumn
Change c = i - 1 to c = i

3. Why start at 11 yet other loops start at 1.

   ```
       For i = 11 To lastrow
   ```
4. Please use more meaning full variables names - it's hard to read
   eg

   ```
   "iCol" for a column counter
   "iRow" for a row counter
   instead of "k" use "ColumnNumWithReqByRPVC"
   etc..
   ```
5. Are you using instr correctly?
   See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811(v=office.15).aspx)

   ```
   InStr([start, ]string1, string2[, compare])
   ```
6. Change

   ```
   Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color 
   To
   ws.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color
   ```

Changing the above might make it work?  let me know.